# leftOf / endOf doesn't work supposed to like xml in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I need help to solve something weird that happened here.

So, I have a layout for the textTitle, currency & the balance and I want it to move the currency & the balance below the titleText and the balance is endOf / rightOf to the currency, but it turns that the balance follows the title texts end. (Please see the screenshot.)

screenshot :

[image: imagelink]

Here is my code :

```
it.addComponent(leftRelativeContainer.also {
         it.addComponent(subtitleBalanceText, params = wrapContentParams)
         it.addComponent(subtitleCurrencyText, params = wrapContentParams)
         it.addComponent(textBalanceText, params = wrapContentParams)

         it.layoutRules {
             subtitleCurrencyText below textBalanceText withMargin Space.x4
             subtitleBalanceText below textBalanceText withMargin Space.x4
             subtitleBalanceText endOf subtitleCurrencyText withMargin Space.x4
         }
}, params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same layout params for all 3 items.  The relative layout rules are in the layout params.  So when you use the same one to all 3, when you add the rules, it will apply the rules to the same instance each time, which... well you're lucky it ended up this good.  Make a separate instance of the layout params for each item.

I also wouldn't really suggest doing this programatically.  It's far more difficult to read/maintain than xml.  Just make this its own tiny XML file and inflate it when needed.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, but what do you mean with separate instance of the layout params for each item? Because i already declare local variable which have value RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT) thank you.

Comment: I know it's easier to use xml, but on this case, it's forced to use programmatically.  So do you mean when i add that 3 components, it should be outside of the params(also's bracket)?